# JPA updating child entity inside @transactional

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have bidirectional one-to-many relationship and try to update child inside transactional method. My parent entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude ={ "subscription","messages","creditCards","privilege"})
@ToString
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "User name should'not be null")
    @Length(min = 5, max = 35)
    @Column(name = "full_name", unique = true)
    @NaturalId
    private String fullName;

    @NotNull(message = "User password should'not be null")
    @Length(min = 8, max = 16)
    private String password;

    @Email(message = "Email should be in valid format!")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone_number",unique = true)
    private long phoneNumber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Subscription subscription;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Privilege privilege;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List <Message> messages;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List <Card> creditCards;

    public User() {
        this.creditCards = new ArrayList <>();
        this.messages = new ArrayList <>();
    }

    public User(Long id, String fullName, String password, Long phoneNumber, String email,
                Role role, Subscription subscription, Privilege privilege) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.password = password;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.role = role;
        this.subscription = subscription;
        this.privilege = privilege;
        this.messages = new ArrayList <>();
        this.creditCards = new ArrayList <>();
    }

    public void addMessage(Message message) {
        messages.add( message );
        message.setUser( this );
    }

    public void removeMessage(Message message) {
        messages.remove( message );
        message.setUser( null );
    }

    public void addCreditCard(Card card) {

        creditCards.add( card );
        card.setUser( this );
    }

    public void removeCreditCard(Card card) {
        creditCards.remove( card );
        card.setUser( null );
    }

    public void setSubscription(Subscription subscription){
           if(subscription==null){
               if(this.subscription!=null){
                   this.subscription.setUser( null );
               }
           }
           else {
               subscription.setUser( this );
           }
           this.subscription=subscription;
    }
}
```

My child:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "card")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"availableFunds","blockedFunds"})
@ToString  (exclude = "user")
public class Card {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "expiration_date", columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate expirationDate;

    @Column(name = "valid_date", columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate validFromDate;

    @NotNull(message = "credit card shouldn't be null!")
    @Column(name = "credit_card_number",unique = true)
    private long creditCardNumber;

    @Column(name = "available_funds")
    private double availableFunds;

    @Column(name = "blocked_funds")
    private double blockedFunds;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "full_name",
            referencedColumnName = "full_name"
    )
    private User user;

    public void addFunds(double amount) {
        availableFunds += amount;
    }

    public void writeOff(double amount) {
        if (amount > availableFunds) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Incorrect amount to write-off!" );
        }
        availableFunds -= amount;
    }

    public void blockFunds(double amount) {
        writeOff( amount );
        blockedFunds += amount;
    }

    public void unBlockFunds(double amount) {
        blockedFunds -= amount;
        addFunds( amount );
    }
}
```

Method in Service layer which fails:

```java
@TransactionalEventListener
 @Transactional(readOnly = false)  
public void onOrderCreatedEvent(OrderCreatedEvent event)
     {
        User retrieved = userDao.findByUserName( event.getOrderDto().getUserDto().getFullName() );
    
        Card card = retrieved.getCreditCard();
        log.debug("lots of info about cards balance" );
    
        card.blockFunds( Double.parseDouble( event.getOrderDto().getBlockedFunds() ) );
    
        /*userDao.update( retrieved ); --not working*/
    
         log.debug("lots of info about cards balance" );
    
    }
```

So, it goes as expected, catching published event, getting Card by its number, blocking funds, but nothing changes in DB afterall:

```
2020-12-01 19:29:53 DEBUG UserService:150 - Card retrieved: 1
card's available funds: 2000.0
2020-12-01 19:29:53 DEBUG UserService:157 - Card retrieved: 1
card's available funds: 2100.0
```

..and no Hibernate's updating logs neither new data in mysql. Where is the pitfall?

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as Spring's @transactional is a notorious trap, I didn't check requirements for new transaction inside service methods. As I got it, due to the fact the first transaction is closed

```
 User retrieved = userDao.findByUserName
```

right after retrieving entity , and I have to start new one to achieve entity manager and merge all changes. So, after adding

> propagation = PROPAGATION.REQUIRES_NEW

JPA started storing child's state.

Comment: *Had to mention, that method started from transaction context, another transactional service.